# "Book time off for some days"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, prepositions

I want to book some past days as time off via a time tracking system, and there is a reply message:

> Cannot book time off **for** past days.

(Meaning that I should have booked time off before leaving, not after leaving.)

I wonder whether *for* is used correctly here. I just see "book something for someone", "book something on some day", and have never seen "book something for some day" before.

Comment: What other preposition would you expect?

Comment: "**For**" seems the correct preposition to me.

Comment: @banh: I think too "For" is correct.......!

Comment: General Reference - *"for"* here simply means *in respect of*

Comment: "I booked my vacation/the dinner reservation for tomorrow" are extremely common.  Google "book dinner for tomorrow".

Answer (score 1):

If you do X "on" day Y, then Y is the date on which event X occurs. But if you do X "for" day Y, then Y is a date associated with event X, not necessarily the date on which you did it.

So if you said, "I was vacationing ON March 1", people would understand you to mean that March 1 is the date you were actually away from work.

If you said, "I entered a vacation day into the timekeeping system ON March 1", we would understand that March 1 was the date that you typed your vacation information into the computer, not the day that you will be away from the office. We do not know what day you will be away.

If you said, "I entered a vacation day into the timekeeping system FOR March 1", we would understand that March 1 is the day that you will be away from work. We do not know what day you typed it into the computer.

It would be quite reasonable to say, "I entered a vacation day into the timekeeping system on March 1 for April 12." That is, on March 1 you typed it in. The day you will be vacationing is April 12.

Answer (score 0):

The most fundamental meaning of *for* not modified in any way.

You can book (reserve) time off (holidays) *for* (concerning) three days (a period), starting next Monday. (in the future).

You can't reserve a time that is already past - your booking is not applicable *for* past days.

Answer (score 0):

The preposition *for* has several meanings, so it may be hard to find an instance where it's used by a credible source *wrongly*.  (Maybe it's simply being used in a way that's unfamiliar to you.)

[**Macmillan**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/for) lists 19 definitions for the word *for*, but I think the one you want is #4:

[image]

Booking vacation time, then, would be a legitimate context for this sense of the word.

Answer (score 0):

The OED’s definition 26 of *for* is ‘As regards, with regard or respect to, concerning.’ That seems to me to cover the use in your example.